# Push-and-silent remote notification: Cancel alert when app running in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

> I want to send a push-and-silent remote notification...meaning... I would
>   like to update data on the device BEFORE (and not at the same time) an alert message is displayed
>   to the user.

#### More Details

<kbd>1</kbd> If the app is **not running**, I want to show the alert, which is why I added the `alert` key in the json.

<kbd>2</kbd> If app is **running in the background**, I want to cancel the alert, and handle the notification silently: by first downloading content, and when ready trigger a local notification.

<kbd>3</kbd> If app is **foreground active** state, alert is not shown, which is great, and I can handle the logic silently.

#### I have this

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "content-available" : 1,
        "alert" : "This is my new notification",
    }
}
```

#### But it's not working because

When the app is running in the background, the alert is not canceled, and is displayed at the same time as being handled silently.

#### So

Is there a way to cancel the alert if app is running in the background?

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to remove alert from payload. Pass only badge and content-available property.
2. Enable Remote notification under your Application capabilities area. It should be under Background more section.

Comment: Never mentioned badge in my question.. not what I'm trying to do. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Patt: Badge is not mandatory either. I asked to add badge as it helps to check that we received silent push or not.